Update to Android 15,How to support 16kb page size on pdf viewer?
My Pdf viewer lib don't support new feature.
https://github.com/DImuthuUpe/AndroidPdfViewer?tab=readme-ov-file
Do somebody have any solution?
I look up this
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/pdf
and find out it only work out at Android SDK 35
I alse check out PdfRenderer, it will cost more memory and get low quality pics.

I guess you mean https://github.com/DImuthuUpe/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/1191 and https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/page-sizes#16kb-emulator (The readme does not mention this). The question is why do you need to use 16kB memory page size in the emulator as this is a very experimental feature from Google
